# Detecting Server and SQL Server errors and showing an error page

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling, iis-6

in my C# code I use try/catch on all my methods, this picks up most of the errors, but some errors like 404 are not picked up.
Does anyone know how to pick up all other errors that occur on the server or if SQL server is down?

thanks

Comment: set up an error page in you web config

Comment: pick up in what way, for logging or redirecting or what?

Answer (score 0):

you should use [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) as error handler in your project...read the link for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your web.config file and specify the following:

```
<customErrors mode="On">
   <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/error404.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```